# Optional Signer from Agent c# sdk

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We are sending a document using the c# sdk to the agent so that the agent can set the other signers that need to sign.  Problem is how do we setup a signer to be optional.  For example in the picture below the agent knows that 2 need to sign it and ignore the third one.  Can this be done?

[image: optional seller option?]

Comment: You don't know before hand whether you need 2 signers or 3 signers, so that you can correctly set number of signer on the envelope?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mark this as resolved.  During my initial development work I didn't have that information now we modified the code to get the number of signers and we can create the Signers object.  Before I was using what was on the template and was wondering if the agent could control the number of signers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that the answer is no.  So I updated our code to determine the number of signers before hand and create it dynamically instead of what is on the template.  The agent doesn't have the ability to control which ones are optional or the developer.